# Flattening a form using iText7

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext7

I am facing an issue in flattening the fields of a PDF document using iText7. The issue I am facing is when the fields on a signed PDF are flattened, the signature becomes invalid.
I am using `PdfAcroForm.FlattenFields()` method. Prior calling to the said method, I specify that only the form fields need to be flattened by using `PdfAcroForm.PartiallyFlattenFields()` method.
Could anyone suggest a solution in which I can flatten the fields on already signed document.

Comment: By modifying a digitally signed document the digital signature becomes invalid _by design_. The core property of a digital signature is the verifiability of integrity of the document signed.

Comment: @OndrejTucny Is there any other way so that fields are not editable after signing on any browser windows?

Comment: Have you considered flattening _before_ signing? Or at least setting the fields locked and read-only? Or using form field locking during signing?

Comment: @mkl In my scenario, I can not flatten the fields before signing. I have to flatten the fields while performing the last signature on the document in case of multiple signatures. However, I have tried to make fields READONLY and it serves the purpose but I am wondering if it causes any issue with signature integrity?

Comment: *"I have to flatten the fields while performing the last signature on the document in case of multiple signatures."* - Ok. Then flattening is no option at all. At least if the previous signatures must remain validatable and valid. *"I have tried to make fields READONLY and it serves the purpose but I am wondering if it causes any issue with signature integrity?"* - That might depend on the certification level of the document. The best option is field locking and document locking. You can do that with `PdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict` with an appropriately initialized `PdfSigFieldLock` object.

Comment: @mkl I am using a field locking and document locking approach but it causes an issue that the form fields in the PDF can still be editable in browsers, For Example: Microsoft Edge. To resolve this issue I decided to use the Field Flattening approach but it is no option. So I am using the approach to make fields read-only along with document locking and field locking. Could you please let me know if you see any issue with this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure but if a PDF is certified, a certification level of form-fill-in-allowed _might_ be at odds with making fields read-only; that change after all is not an actual form _fill-in_ but a form field _functionality change_. So I would at least test how current Adobe Acrobat reacts in such situations. Other than that it's ok.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for your valuable guidance

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the said issue and identified a workaround for field flattening on a signed document. There is an issue with `PdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict` that even though it locks the form in Adobe and does not allow to change/update form fields value but the form is still editable in browsers like Microsoft Edge. The solution I found against this is to make all fields in PDF **ReadOnly**. By using this approach with PDF having existing signatures, fields are not editable in browsers neither the signature validity is affected. This solution can be implemented to fit different scenarios and may not be suitable under conditions like PDF having a certified policy of form filling and annotations.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Flattening form fields produces an update at the page content level. Even when you flatten in append mode (i.e. by appending data to the end of the file that's not covered by the prior signatures), any PDF signature validator worth its salt will reject changes of that type.

Locking form fields in multi-signature workflows can only be done (semi-)reasonably using field locks/FieldMDP. See 12.8.2.4 in ISO 32000-2:2020, and also Table 236. The corresponding clause numbers in ISO 32000-1:2008 are 12.8.2.4 and 12.7.4.5.

Beware: validator behaviour for *enforcing* FieldMDP is not standardised, so the semantics aren't guaranteed to be identical across vendors.

Comment: iText does support field and document locking, see the `PdfSigner.SetFieldLockDict` method and the `PdfSigFieldLock` class.